# MySQL update query for duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want a SQL updation such that :

Assume I have following table in MySQL database

**titles**

*id*   *title*
1   hello
2   hello
3   hi
4   sometext
5   hi
6   hello

I want this table to be Updated such that there are unique titles.

**titles**

*id*   *title*
1   hello
2   hello1
3   hi
4   sometext
5   hi1
6   hello2

Actually I am working on a migration script where in the Unique titles constraint was not used initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update titles t
inner join
(
SELECT    id,
          title,
          case when title=@curTitle then @curRank := @curRank + 1 else @curRank:=0 end,
          @curTitle:=title,
          @curRank as rank
FROM      titles t, (SELECT @curRank := 0,@curTitle="") r
ORDER BY  title
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.title = concat(t1.title,case when rank = 0 then "" else rank end)
;
```

Or, a probably more efficient way would be to take take Strawberry's answer and turn it into an UPDATE statement in a similar fashion....

Hence:

```
update titles t
inner join 
(
SELECT x.id
     , concat(x.title,CASE WHEN y.id IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(y.id) ELSE "" END) newTitle 
from titles x
  LEFT 
  JOIN titles y 
    ON y.title = x.title 
   AND y.id < x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.title = t1.newTitle
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN y.id IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(y.id) ELSE '' END rank 
  FROM titles x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN titles y 
    ON y.title = x.title 
   AND y.id < x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
```

Comment: Does not work atleast in MySQL. And I want UPDATION not SELECT

Comment: Of course it works. The business of transfroming this to an UPDATE (if you're sure that that's what you want!) is triviwal.